# Yahoo Weather API sometimes works sometimes not

Tags: api, yahoo-api, yahoo-weather-api

Im developing an APP which is getting the weather time from a query to Yahoo API.

[Here is my query](https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20woeid%20in(select%20woeid%20from%20geo.places(1)%20where%20text%3D%22Vigo%20Espa%C3%B1a%20%22)) maybe it works the first time, but If you refresh the browser maybe it dosnt work.

[Here is the documentation](https://developer.yahoo.com/weather/)

And the limits:

> Rate Limits
>   Use of the Yahoo Weather API should not exceed reasonable request volume. Access is limited to 2,000 signed calls per day.

Should I use an API key? or what is the problem? 
Thanks!